# Razor view: Minify text with three dots and show full text with tooltip

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have the following code to display dots at the end of a string if it is longer than a limit. But I also want to display a tooltip with the full text on hover. I am not sure how to implement that to a razor view element.

```
@(item.Data.Title.Length > 10 ? item.Data.Title.Substring(0, 10) + "..." : item.Data.Title)
```

Comment: Consider using css to style you element (refer [Truncate String with Ellipsis](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/truncate-string-with-ellipsis/)). And then you could also use the jquery `.hover()` event to toggle the style and display the full text.

Comment: did you solve the problem?

Answer (score 4):

You can implement tooltip via jquery and bootstrap like following.

Jsfiddle example : https://jsfiddle.net/z4upto60/

**cshtml:**

```
<div> 
    <a data-toggle="tooltip" title="@item.Data.Title">
        @(item.Data.Title.Length > 10 ? item.Data.Title.Substring(0, 10) + "..." : item.Data.Title)
    </a>
</div>
```

**jquery:**

```
if('@item.Data.Title.Length' > 10)
{
   $('a[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip({
      animated: 'fade',
      placement: 'bottom',
   });
}
```